# How to describe a column programmatically in select part of request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql, pg

There is the following scope:

```
scope :by_radius,   ->(lat, lng, rad) { select("*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(#{lat})) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(#{lng})) + sin(radians(#{lat})) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance").having("distance <= #{rad}") }
```

As you can see, I describe 'distance' column in SELECT part of request and use it in HAVING part, but I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist
```

If I understand right the problem exists in PostgreSQL. How can I fix it? I use this request for getting all points by radius and current latitude/longitude. I don't want to use Geocoder, I think the solution with searching in database will works faster.

Comment: Might be simplistic, but are you sure you have a `distance` column in your database?

Comment: I created this column through 'As'

Answer (score 1):

[`having`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having) can be used only if you're using [`group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group). What you're looking for is a simple `where` :

```
scope :by_radius, ->(lat, lng, rad) { select("*, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(#{lat})) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(#{lng})) + sin(radians(#{lat})) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance").where("distance <= #{rad}") }
```